# gl_ModelViewMatrixInverseTranspose in threejs

Tags: matrix, three.js, webgl, shader

In my attemp to write my own custom shader (I am using a `THREE.ShaderMaterial`), I need to set its WebGL's built-in `gl_ModelViewMatrixInverseTranspose` uniform (as seen on http://mew.cx/glsl_quickref.pdf). I noticed some uniforms are already automatically passed to the shader, for instance `gl_ModelViewMatrix` and `gl_ProjectionMatrix` are already accounted for, by threejs' `modelViewMatrix` and `projectionMatrix` respectively. `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix`, on the other hand, seems to be missing, but I noticed some examples where it can easily be computed inside the shader as `projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix`. So my question is: am I to manually compute `gl_ModelViewMatrixInverseTranspose` inside my shader starting from `modelViewMatrix` (and if so, how?) or is there a unform (possibily merged inside my definition of `THREE.ShaderMaterial` with `THREE.UniformsUtils.merge`) that already handles it? Cheers.

Comment: WebGL doesn't have `gl_ModelViewMatrixInverseTranspose` or any other default matrices. That's an old deprecated OpenGL thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Three.js shader the inverse transpose of modelViewMatrix is called `normalMatrix`.

It is automatically passed into the shaders so you don't need to do any work to get it.

```
// = inverse transpose of modelViewMatrix
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
```

For reference [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram) are the built-in uniform and attributes Three.js has.

Comment: To be precise, the 3x3 `normalMatrix` is the transpose of the inverse of the upper 3x3 sub-matrix of the 4x4 `modelViewMatrix`